# Codeigniter:Update Image and Display Current image if I don't want to update old image

Tags: codeigniter, controller, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-query-builder

I'm stuck on a problem with updating image. I've created image upload which works fine but I also want it to be updated. When I add a need image it updates correctly but I if don't want to change the image and leave it as it is, then my current image can't be retrieve.

Please help me

**Here is my code:**

**my model update**

```
 function updateDatasale($id){
          
          $data=array(
 
              'mayor_permit_attachment'=>$this->mayors_attachment()
             
              
          );
          $this->db->where('id',$id);
          $this->db->update('tickets',$data);
      }

function mayors_attachment(){

            $pic=array(
                'upload_path'=>'./uploads/',
                'allowed_types'=>'gif|jpg|png',
                'max_size'=>4000,
                'max_width'=>10024,
                'max_height'=>10024,
            );
            $this->load->library("upload",$pic);
            
            if($this->upload->do_upload('mayors_attachment')){
                $fb=$this->upload->data();
                $fd=$fb['file_name'];
                return $fd;
            }
            else{
                $data = "null";
                return $data;
            }

 }
```

**controller**

```
public function updatesales($id){
    $this->TicketReply_model->updateDatasale($id);
    redirect("accepttask");
}
```

**views**

```
<tr>
  <td>
      <span class="text-danger text-bold">
           <label>Mayors Permit:</label>
             <input type="file" name="mayors_attachment" >                           
 </td>  
</tr>
```

Comment: have your problem is solved or not??

Comment: not yet. Additional for my problem is every time I do update, the image return null in database if I did not select any image

Comment: please check my answer please.

Comment: I tried your answer but still nothing happen .. I do make a variable to store may old image but still after updating the old image cant retrieve  ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way that I've used to solve this kind of problem was to store the file name (or the full path) in a session or cookie. After storing, you can easily retrieve this detail and use it wherever you want.

In your upload file check block:

```
if($this->upload->do_upload('mayors_attachment')){
// other code here
$attachment_session_data = array('attachment_file' => $fb['full_path']); // or the file_name if your prefer
$this->session->set_userdata($attachment_session_data); // add to session
// return normally
}
```

Then in your view file, using a `value` attribute for a file input doesn't count and it is not being submitted to the form. So, a workaround will be to `echo` an `img` tag, to show the image, then while processing the form, you would check if a new value is entered in the input file and also if a session already exists the previously entered image.

Something like so:

**VIEW FILE**

```
<tr>
  <td>
      <span class="text-danger text-bold">
           <label>Mayors Permit:</label>
             <input type="file" name="mayors_attachment" >   
             <img src="<?php echo $this->session->attachment_file; ?>">
 </td>  
</tr>
```

Ideally, `$this->session->attachment_file` should be in your controller and saved as part of the `$data` array that will be sent to the view, then you can just call or echo the variable in the view file. *(I hope you get the point).*

Then in your **CONTROLLER** or **MODEL**:

```
// Check if session exists and input file is empty
if ( $this->session->attachment_file && empty($_FILES) )
{
    // No file was entered, no need to upload
}
else 
{
    // New file was entered, do upload.
}
```

Comment: Glad to help. If this answer solved your problem, please mark as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

First You have to store `hidden` image from database with input type file option.
and then check in controller function with `if else{}` image is available or not?

**views**

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo base_url().'ControllerName/updateImageData/'.$id;?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
<tr>
  <td>
      <span class="text-danger text-bold">
           <label>Mayors Permit:</label>

           //store hidden image from database.

           <input type="hidden" name="mayors_attachment_oldimage"  value="<?php echo $mayors_attachment;?>">
           
           <input type="file" name="mayors_attachment">                           
 </td>  
</tr>

<button class="btn btn-primary form-control" type="submit">Update Details</button>

</form>
```

**Controller Code :**

```
 public function updateImageData($aid)
    {       
         if($_FILES['mayors_attachment']['name']!=""){

             $config['upload_path'] = "./assets/uploads/mayors_attachment/";
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpeg|png|jpg';
            $this->load->library('upload',$config);
            $this->path = './assets/uploads/mayors_attachment/';

           $this->upload->initialize($config);

            if (!$this->upload->do_upload('mayors_attachment'))
            {
              $error = array('error'=>$this->upload->display_errors());
           }else{
           $imageUpload = $this->upload->data();
           $mayors_attachment_image_name=$imageUpload['file_name'];
            }
        }
         else{
                $mayors_attachment_image_name=$this->input->post('mayors_attachment_oldimage');
             
            }
            
         $insertdata = array(
              'mayors_attachment'=>$mayors_attachment_image_name);  
            
        $insertQuery = $this->db->where('id',$aid)->update('tickets',$insertdata);  
    }
```

Comment: if your problem is solved then please marked as accepted answer by green tick for future readers also.

Comment: what happens ??